# Disable Cache in Network tab works but Ctrl+F5 or Shift+F5 doesn't in Edge and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, browser-cache

I am taking over a large asp.net mvc application and I noticed this strange behavior in **Edge** and **Chrome** - when I do **Ctrl+F5 or Shift+F5**, my javascript changes are not appearing in my browser but if I have **Disable Cache** in Network tab, then the latest is pulled.

I am stumped at this behavior, can someone explain this? Since this is happening in both browsers, I suspect there is some caching related config in the web application that is causing this - but I am not sure what this could be!

Edge version is 102.0.1245.39

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue but failed, it works fine. What is the version of the Microsoft Edge? Maybe you can check if the hard refresh shortcut in Edge has been changed. Something like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSs14.png).

Comment: @XudongPeng, edited above with Edge version. And how do I get to this "Shortcuts" settings that you show in your screenshot?

Comment: Just press `F12` in Edge to open devtools, and then make sure the focus inside the devtools and press `F1`. In `Settings`, you will find the `shortcuts` section in the list.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 is enabled. Btw, I take back what I said about chrome, issue is happening in Chrome as well!

Comment: If this is the case, I'm afraid I can't determine the cause of the problem, maybe there's something wrong with the keyboard? Because in my test it works fine :)

Comment: Ctrl+F5 only updates updates the page itself and resources what attached to it (js, html, etc). Elements created by JS (`document.createElement("script").src = ...`, `fetch`),will still use cached variants. Check the script resource Initiator column in Network tab.